# Linux Crontab. 'Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string' al hacer un backup pero esta bien

Tags: linux, bash, crontab

tengo en mi crontab este `mysqldump` para hacer un backup de mi bd:

```
0 5 * * mon,wed,thu,fri root mysqldump test > /var/backups/databases/test_$( date '+%F_%H:%M:%S' ).sql
```

Y estoy viendo que no me ha hecho ningun backup de dicha BD, me he ido a `/var/mail/root` y he encontrado errores del crontab que he recibido como alertas, en concreto:

```
To: root
Subject: Cron <xxxr> mysqldump   test  > /var/backups/databases/database_test_$( date '+
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: xxx
X-Cron-Env: xxx
X-Cron-Env: xxx
X-Cron-Env: xxx
Message-Id: xxx
Date: Mon, 12 Apr 2021 03:00:01 +0000 (UTC)

/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Entonces, por el error que me da, interpreto que no termina de leer la linea y corta el script cuando va por `data ' +...` por eso me da un error de syntax. Pero claro, no tiene sentido aparente alguno, verdad? ¿Por que iba a cortar ahi?

De hecho he probado el script a mano y tira bien.

**Actualizacion**

Tengo estos entornos en el crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traducido del manual de [crontab](/questions/tagged/crontab):

> Un caracter `%` en el comando, a menos que sea escapado con `\`, será sustituido por un caracter de nueva linea, y todos los datos después del primer `%` serán enviados al comando como entrada estándar.

Por eso corta la línea, por lo que debes escapar el formato de la fecha:

```
$( date '+\%F_\%H:\%M:\%S' )
```

Comment: Perfecto. Una pregunta de Linux principiante. Como haces para averiguar la solución. Es decir. Buscas en man o algo? Es que quiero ser autodidacta con esto pues Linux tiene mil cosas como estás de que para un entorno hay q hacer tal pero en otro no.. tal y cual. Son tantas cosas que veo que son muy pejigueras  que me gustaría no aprenderlo como tal sino ir a buscar dudas que me surjan y problemas como este que son muuuuuuy concretos.

Comment: Así es, `man` es el primer recurso.

Comment: una pregunta, si yo por ejemplo en vez de usar el comando como tal usara un fichero sh, llamese `backups.sh` tendria que escapar tambien los `%` ? Es que de ser asi un script depende del entorno. Un saludo. @Sal

Comment: @joseangel El escapar -que no es exclusivo de crontab- depende del contexto. En tu caso, la solución alterna es precisamente meter el comando (sin escapar) en un script.